# Displaying the sum in the table using angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to display the total of each field array in the table below using angular 4. For e.g the total of captiveInsPremiumPaid needs to be displayed near Premium paid. Is there an inbuilt angular function that lets me do directly in Html or do I need to total in the component and bind it to the html. Either way could you let me know how do i go about it

[image]

The definition of the object that I am trying to read is as follows

```
 export interface NpvResults  {

            captiveInsYear: number[];
            captiveInsPremiumPaid: number[];
            captiveInsTaxDeduction: number[];
            captiveInsLoanToParent: number[];
            captiveInsCapitalContribution: number[];
            captiveDividentDistribution: number[];
            captiveInsTerminalValue: number[];

        }
```

Hardcoded values in the component for testing purpose

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.sourceResults = Object.assign({} as BackendDto.NpvResults) ;

        this.sourceResults.captiveInsYear = [1,2,3,4,5];
        this.sourceResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid = [-112000,568676,3343456,7676343,55656];
        this.sourceResults.captiveInsTaxDeduction = [44800,565656,347673,56565,34343];
        this.sourceResults.captiveInsLoanToParent = [0,3434,34346,5563,4545,343];
        this.sourceResults.captiveInsCapitalContribution = [0,347455,3435665,67676,34343];
        this.sourceResults.captiveDividentDistribution = [-2038328.6785651783,4545,4545,4545,56565];
        this.sourceResults.captiveInsTerminalValue = [0,5656,45454,23434,5656];

        }
```

The html table is below

```
<div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
     <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
     <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"><h6>Captive Option</h6></div>
 </div>
 <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
     <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Premium Paid</div>
     <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"> {{NpvResults?.captiveInsPremiumPaid|number:'.0-3'}} </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Tax Deduction</div>
    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"> {{NpvResults?.captiveInsTaxDeduction|number:'.0-3'}}</div>
</div>
 <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Loan to Parent</div>
    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">{{NpvResults?.captiveInsLoanToParent|number:'.0-3'}}</div>
 </div> 
 <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Capital Contribution/Distribution</div>
    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"> {{NpvResults?.captiveInsCapitalContribution|number:'.0-3'}} </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in your html to sum a list of values in an array.

```
{{NpvResults?.captiveInsPremiumPaid.reduce(sum,0) | number:'.0-3'}}
```

and then in your component:

```
public sum = (total, currentValue) => total + currentValue;
```

Working example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/cfyREeczoJ9UjFyDxkQv?p=preview

Comment: Not sure why I am getting this error TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Comment: @Tom you have to add an initial value when the array is empty, see update:  `NpvResults?.captiveInsPremiumPaid.reduce(sum , 0)`